# How to get two objects each from an ajax call and compare them?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help getting two pieces of data, and comparing them.

What I am trying to create here is a system for associating groups with an employee. While on the employee's details page, the user has a button to show a popup. In this popup there is a list of groups the employee can be associated with. The list (checkbox inputs arrange as a buttonset) is populate with all groups, then I would like to have each group the employee is already associated with to be checked, so they show highlighted.

I am trying to accomplish this with the following code (but failing):

```
function loadAllGroups() {
var iGroupID;
var iGroupName;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Processes/process_Groups.aspx/GetGroups',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: '{}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (aData) {
        var AllGroups = aData.d;
        var EmployeeGroups;
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST',
            url: '../Processes/process_Groups.aspx/GetGroupsPerEmployee',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{EmployeeID: ' + EmployeeID + '}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:
                function (eData) {
                    EmployeeGroups = eData.d;
                },
            error:
                function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { errorBox.append(jqXHR.responseText); } 
        });
        $.each(AllGroups, function (aIndex, aGroup) {
            var iChecked = '';
            $.each(aGroup, function (aKey, aVal) {
                if (aKey == 'GroupID') { iGroupID = aVal }
                if (aKey == 'GroupName') { iGroupName = aVal }
            });
            $.each(EmployeeGroups, function (eIndex, eGroup) {
                $.each(eGroup, function (eKey, eVal) {
                    if (eKey == 'GroupID') {
                        if (iGroupID == eVal) { iChecked = 'checked="checked"' } else { iChecked = '' }
                    }
                });
            });
        GroupsList.append('<input type="checkbox" id="Group_' + iGroupID + '" value="' + iGroupID + '" ' + iChecked + ' /><label for="Group_' + iGroupID + '">' + iGroupName + '</label>');
        });
        GroupsList.buttonsetv();
    },
    error:
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { errorBox.append(jqXHR.responseText); }
});
}
```

I assume doing an ajax call within an ajax call is a No-No. I just don't know how else to access the two objects of data that are returned by each ajax call, in a way to compare them.

Comment: I dont see how another ajax call on the success of the first one could be a problem? What errors are there?

Comment: @RTully I was getting EmployeeGroups return as 'undefined', I think it has to do with whether the GetGroupsPerEmployee ajax call returned a value before the rest of the following code executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the inner ajax call and 'EmployeeGroups' variable out of first ajax call, and put it at the top after the first variable declarations. This should still accomplish the same, just without the nasty ajax inception.

Comment: This seems to have a better outcome than before, although randomly no groups will load. I still think there is an issue depending upon whether one of the ajax calls returns a value before the subsequent code is executed.

Comment: Make sure that the ajax call is returning something also (maybe throw in a quick alert just to be sure). If you want to be 100% sure that the ajax isn't running before the other call is finished, throw in a pause statement for a second or something long enough to let the first finish. I know I had a bug once when using slower mobile devices where i had to wait for 250 ms in order for it to render properly. Let me know how it goes!